# Why would 'w' output show an incorrect number of logged-in users?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

The `w` output on my Ubuntu 10.10 machine shows the following:

```
# w
 23:23:04 up 188 days, 11:35,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
mike     pts/0    051.203-40-32.ft 23:12    0.00s  0.09s  0.02s sshd: mike [priv]

# exit

$ w
 23:24:47 up 188 days, 11:36,  2 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.06, 0.06
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
mike     pts/0    051.203-40-32.ft 23:12    0.00s  0.04s  0.00s w
```

What I can't figure out is, why does it show `2 users` when I'm the only one logged in?

Should I be worried that I have a rootkit feeding me inaccurate data?

Answer (score 1):

I think terminal counts as another user.

Comment: What do you mean by "terminal"? What *exactly* counts?